# Slowing down CAGradientLayer animation

Tags: swift, swift3, cabasicanimation, cagradientlayer

I want to animate a three colored gradient *slowly*.

I have a custom `UIView` like so:

```
class MyView: UIView, CAAnimationDelegate {

  lazy var gradientLayer: CAGradientLayer = {
        let l = CAGradientLayer()
        l.frame = self.frame
        l.colors = self.colors
        l.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
        l.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1, y: 0)
        l.mask = self.textLayer
        return l
    }()

    lazy var textLayer: CATextLayer = {
        let l = CATextLayer()
        l.frame = self.frame
        l.string = "test".uppercased()
        l.fontSize = 23
        return l
    }()

    var colors: [CGColor] =  [
            UIColor.red.cgColor,
            UIColor.purple.cgColor,
            UIColor.blue.cgColor
            ]

    init() {
    ...
    self.layer.addSublayer(gradientLayer)

    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    func animate() {

      var newColors = colors
      let lastColor: CGColor = newColors.last!
      newColors.removeLast()
      newColors.insert(lastColor, at: 0)

      colors: newColors
      gradientLayer.colors = newColors

      let a = CABasicAnimation(keyPath:"colors")
      a.toValue = newColors
      a.duration = 0.1
      a.isRemovedOnCompletion = true
      a.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards
      a.delegate = self

      gradientLayer.add(a, forKey:"animateGradient")

    }

    func animationDidStop(_ anim: CAAnimation, finished flag: Bool) {

          animate()
    }

}
```

This works, but is very fast. How can I slow the animation down, without it getting blocky? 
Do I have to add a couple hundred colors to the `colors` array so that it has enough to cycle through?

Thanks

Comment: wouldnt it be just changing a.duration = 0.1 to something slower?

Comment: making `duration` smaller causes the animation to go faster. making it larger and you don't have a fluid animation. It is more like a jump, not an animation.

Comment: You can use `UIColor` `red` `green` `blue` `alpha` method and change their values within your animation block. But you need to come up with an algorithm that does the combinations of `RGB` in a way it covers your three primary colors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

unless I'm missing something in your code you haven't set a fromValue in the animation. Surely you need to set this to the previous value of colors before you switch colors to newColors:

```
func animate() {
  let oldColors = colors
  var newColors = colors
  let lastColor: CGColor = newColors.last!
  newColors.removeLast()
  newColors.insert(lastColor, at: 0)

  colors = newColors
  gradientLayer.colors = newColors

  let a = CABasicAnimation(keyPath:"colors")
  // New line here ->
  a.fromValue = oldColors
  a.toValue = newColors
  a.duration = 0.1
  a.isRemovedOnCompletion = true
  a.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards
  a.delegate = self

  gradientLayer.add(a, forKey:"animateGradient")

}
```

This will be the reason you are not really getting an animation- your code was set up effectively to create a delayed snap transition.

Comment: I am getting an animation it is just too quick... you see it fly by... I want it to take something like a minute for one cycle to complete.

Comment: If you try my code and change duration to 60 does it slow down (apologies I am away from my desk and can't test the code)?